# How to create citations that link to external source directly?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

Let's say I have a citation '[1]'. On clicking on '1', I would like to have a webpage pop up corresponding to the URL in the relevant bibtex entry. Also, I would like bibtex/biblatex to not generate the 'References' section. If the bibtex entry does not have a \url field, then pdflatex/bibtex should error out. I did fair research and did a bit of prompt engineering with ChatGPT as well but had no success. Help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome. // Please EDIT your question and augment it with some code, which compiles, shows your problem and is minimalistic. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `biblatex` this is as easy as modifying the `bibhyperref` field format to get the desired links and not issuing `\printbibliography` to drop the bibliography at the end.

The following will link the citation to the DOI or URL if available and will error if neither DOI nor URL are available.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
      {\PackageError{biblatex}
         {No URL/DOI for entry \thefield{entrykey}}
         {I won't be able to link this entry properly.}%
       #1}
      {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson} (DOI)

ipsum \autocite{ctan} (URL)

dolor \autocite{worman} (no link)
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked citations]

Comment: Thanks @moewe for helping out. Appreciate it. This is awesome. Quick follow up: I see the following in the PDF with the text within the square brackets being bold. Any idea what I may be missing herein? 

`Lorem [sigfridsson] (DOI) 

ipsum [ctan] (URL) 

dolor [worman] (no link) `

Comment: @arunkejariwal You probably did not run Biber. A document with `biblatex` needs to be compiled with Biber and not with BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for more on what BibTeX and Biber do and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber fo you.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. I got it working. One more thing: In the screenshot you shared above, why are the citations number <2, 1, 3>, not <1, 2, 3>. As there's no bibliography at the end (when it exists, some prefer it to be alphabetically sorted and hence the citations numbers have no particular ordering), I would prefer to have an increasing order. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind. Added `sorting=none` and it worked.